# How to access or modify Android ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to know how to modify message data, neither root nor default application in android application

Goal is block number list manager and i want to receive message of to filtered number I’ve looked [BlockNumberContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BlockedNumberContract) api but this require permission like default sms/dialer application, carrier application Only default application(User is chosen application) will have access MMS-SMS ContentProvider when on android 4.4+ I was check to [LINK](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

Also, If you know anything else, please let me know them

Additionally if impossible on android application level, Please another level any solutions and any ideas let me know

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  That's the entire reason they created the Default Messaging App-  to prevent you from doing it.  You need to be the default messaging app to do this-  or at least root and directly edit the db.